Use same route in svelte, but show different content per user role
In sveltekit, I want to use route like /home for two types of user, but having different content:

If a user is admin it should show a list of users
If a user is not an admin, it should show a list of tasks

This would mean that those two outcomes should have different +page.ts to use load function to get the page data.
Whole thing is an SPA, so server part of the sveltekit is not used.
Is this possible?
PS. It is kind of opposite of this question

I do not think this is possible at the routing level.
Would probably return different objects depending on role and extract the content to separate components (these can be in the same directory as the +page.svelte).
// (in page load function or directly in the backend)
if (/* role check for admin */) {
  return { type: 'admin', users: /* ... */, ... };
else
  return { type: 'user': tasks: /* ... */, ... };

{#if data.type == 'admin'}
  <AdminView users={data.users} />
{:else if data.type == 'user'}
  <UserView tasks={data.tasks} />
{/if}


And this role check would be done in the +page.ts?

The load function, if you want to use that.

If that would incur additional round trips, all of that logic can be delegated to your backend, so it directly provides the correct page data for the user.

This is what I thought. Already I switch the component, similar to what you suggested. Thanks!
